# RTMP encoder in JS?

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc, rtmp

I am using now OBS to push a stream to a RTMP server.

That was also possible with Flash that could puhs a stream to a RTMP server.

However, I cannot find any JS manner to do that. I found some solutions based on FFMPEG intermediate like:
https://github.com/chenxiaoqino/getusermedia-to-rtmp

Are there some pure JS implementations of publishing a RTMP stream ?

browser (no flash)-------------->RTMP server

Answer (score 1):

No, it’s not possible. Browsers do not support RTMP, and also do not allow you to open a raw socket, so there is now way to add it via a library.

Comment: this is possible. You capture raw data with mediaRecorder  problem is then to convert the chunk to rtmp chunck

Comment: It’s 100% not possible unless you tunnel to over websocket, http, or WebRTC. Yes, you can make an rtmp packet in memory, but then what do you do with it? There is not RTMP compatible transport to send it over, no way to connect to an RTMP server.